# Uniform continuity preserved under extension of function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Assume that $f$ and $f'$ are uniformly continuous functions $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$. Let $a$ be an irrational number, and define $\overline f$ as the extension of $f$ to $\mathbb Q\cup\{a\}$ such that $\overline f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$. I need to prove that also $\overline f'$ is uniformly continuous (and defined on all of $\mathbb Q\cup\{a\}$).

The proof can not make use of any theorems about derivatives. That is, it must proceed directly from the definition of the derivative.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a very good reason I couldn't prove it: the proposition is false! [Minkowski's_question_mark_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_question_mark_function) is a counter-example. For all rational $q$, $f'(q)$ is $0$, but there are irrational $a$ such that $f'(a)$ is not $0$.